# Heroku: Idling causes Rails app to crash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn

I'm trying to figure out what reason caused Rails application to crash with code H10 and cannot find explanation so far.

Could you help me to find explanation?

How can I prevent same errors in future?

Here is snippet from log:

```
...
2016-01-17T21:54:05.302457+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.mysite.com request_id=3510edb8-2f3e-4b61-a88d-7513ae903db6 fwd="84.228.32.70" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=1605
2016-01-17T22:29:00.091881+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2016-01-17T22:29:00.092560+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2016-01-17T22:29:00.098060+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2016-01-17T22:29:01.913394+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 11956 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2016-01-17T22:29:02.732162+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-01-17T22:29:02.732072 #3]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2016-01-17T22:29:03.902254+00:00 app[web.1]: Translating routes (default locale: he)
2016-01-17T22:29:04.253291+00:00 app[web.1]: Translating routes (default locale: he)
2016-01-17T22:29:04.302976+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-01-17T22:29:04.302899 #3]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:11956 fd=9
2016-01-17T22:29:04.369997+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-01-17T22:29:04.659682+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-01-17T22:29:05.359037+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUITUnicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUIT
Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead
2016-01-17T22:29:05.359041+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-17T22:29:05.359071+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-17T22:29:05.359309+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUIT
2016-01-17T22:29:05.562201+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-01-17T22:29:05.562085 #3]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 6 exit 0> worker=0
2016-01-17T22:29:05.562310+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-01-17T22:29:05.562251 #3]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 9 exit 0> worker=1
2016-01-17T22:29:05.562438+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-01-17T22:29:05.562381 #3]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 12 exit 0> worker=2
2016-01-17T22:29:05.562554+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-01-17T22:29:05.562497 #3]  INFO -- : master complete
2016-01-17T22:29:05.635381+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-01-17T22:29:05.635217 #6]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
2016-01-17T22:29:05.638904+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-01-17T22:29:05.638616 #9]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
2016-01-17T22:29:05.636719+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-01-17T22:29:05.636605 #3]  INFO -- : master process ready
2016-01-17T22:29:05.642691+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-01-17T22:29:05.642574 #12]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
2016-01-17T22:29:06.594700+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-01-17T22:33:43.910830+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2016-01-17T22:33:57.320083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-01-17T22:34:00.699503+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead
2016-01-17T22:34:00.723242+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUIT
2016-01-17T22:34:00.711418+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUIT
2016-01-17T22:34:01.145671+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-01-17T22:34:01.145535 #3]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 6 exit 0> worker=0
2016-01-17T22:34:01.145769+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-01-17T22:34:01.145711 #3]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 9 exit 0> worker=1
2016-01-17T22:34:01.259225+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-01-17T22:34:01.246160 #3]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 12 exit 0> worker=2
2016-01-17T22:34:01.259232+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-01-17T22:34:01.246321 #3]  INFO -- : master complete
2016-01-17T22:34:02.405879+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-01-17T23:22:21.878317+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/feeds/articles" host=www.mysite.com request_id=5a1e5028-1175-4c81-a4a2-60960c0f92fe fwd="100.43.85.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-01-17T23:22:26.023560+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/feeds/articles" host=www.mysite.com request_id=74544d24-8f7f-43b7-96a5-5928258fc959 fwd="141.8.143.187" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-01-17T23:22:29.998272+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/feeds/articles" host=www.mysite.com request_id=ee62e215-e8d9-41e7-9504-8e600d60b822 fwd="100.43.81.154" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
...
```

Content of ./config/unicorn.rb

```
# config/unicorn.rb

worker_processes Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 3)
timeout Integer(ENV['WEB_TIMEOUT'] || 15)
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end  

after_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

May this configuration cause H10 errors?

Comment: Is this a new app you recently deployed to heroku? Did you run migrations?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new app you recently deployed to heroku? Did you run migrations? Make sure you have all your dependencies declared in the Gemfile. If you're requiring some gem from your code but it's not in the Gemfile it will crash on boot up in Heroku even though it works on your local machine because you may have gem installed it and it's available but heroku won't have it unless its in the Gemfile. The endpoint that's giving this error is `/feeds/articles` start looking there.

Comment: diego.greyrobot This app is running already over 2 years and it's a first time I noticed such Heroku's error code. It may happen that such error was hidden for me all this time. Regarding routes you're mentioned, I've copied just first 3 errors. Any URL path generate such error, even /robots.txt

Comment: can you run any code in the console? `heroku run rails c`

Comment: Yes. Running code within attached Heroku's console is working without any problem. BUT. This probably solved by restarting process I did with "heroku restart -a myapp" after noticed a problem.